The boundness of sequence $\{y^{k+\frac{1}{2}}\}$
Let sequence $\{y^{k+\frac{1}{2}}\}$ generated by
$$
y^{k+\frac{1}{2}}=y^{k}+z^{k},
$$
where $z^{k}$ not be necessary bounded. If $\{y^{k+\frac{1}{2}}\}$ is bounded, can we deduce
$\{y^{k}\}$ is bounded?
Here is my consideration, is it right?
If we take $y^{k+\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{2}$, $y^{k}=n+\frac{1}{4}$ and $z^{k}=\frac{1}{4}-n$, then
$\{y^{k}\}$ is unbounded. If $\{z^{k}\}$ is bounded, then $\{y^{k}\}$ is must bounded.

Why is the sequence called $y^{k+\frac{1}{2}}$? It's just a genuinely difference sequence, so couldn't we write $$x_k=y_k+z_k?$$

yes, we can write it as $x_k=y_k+z_k$.

Your solution looks correct, except it should be $$y^k=\color{red}{k}+\frac{1}{4}$$ and not $$y^k=\color{red}{n}+\frac{1}{4}.$$
Let $A$ denote the set of all real-valued sequences and let $B$ denote the set of real-valued, bounded sequences. Note that $y+z\in B$ for $y,z\in B$. Moreover, $y\in   B$ iff $-y\in B$. From this it follows that if $t\in B$, then for any $s\in A$, $s+t\in B$ iff $s\in B$. To see this, note that if $s\in B$, then $s+t\in B$, since the sum of bounded sequences is bounded.

Conversely, if $s+t\in B$, let $r=s+t$ and note that $$s=r+(-t),$$ and $r,-t\in B$. So if $s+t\in B$, $s\in B$. This shows that if $z$ and $x$ are bounded (where $x=y+z$), then $y$ is bounded. However, for any unbounded sequence $u$ and bounded sequences $a,b$,we can take $$y=a+u$$ and $$t=-u+b$$ to get examples where $y,z\notin B$ but $y+z=a+b\in B$.
